# How to use arrange_ in my function?

Tags: r, dplyr

Basically my problem is I don't understand how to assign multiple variable names as a "comma separated list" for my own function. My function is written as below:

```
tsf <- function(df, ...){
    df<- arrange_(df, .dots = substitute(...))
    other stuff
  return(df)
}
```

but if I use it as

```
t <- tsf(df, var1, var2)
```

the dataframe will only be arranged on the basis of var1, instead of as in arrange(df, var1, var2) which it will be arranged by both.

How should I correct my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `alist` to capture the values of the dots arguments in a list.

```
tsf <- function(df, ...){
  dots <- eval(substitute(alist(...)))
  dots <- vapply(dots,
                 deparse,
                 character(1))
  df <- dplyr::arrange_(df, .dots = dots)
  return(df)
}

tsf(mtcars, am, carb, gear)
```

See the section on "Capturing unevaluated …" at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Answer (score 2):

See [the vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#capturing-multiple-variables):

```
library(dplyr)
packageVersion("dplyr")
# [1] ‘0.5.0.9004’
tsf <- function(df, ...){
  df<- arrange(df, !!!quos(...))
  return(df)
}
tsf(mtcars, vs, cyl)
```

[Also note](https://blog.rstudio.org/2017/04/13/dplyr-0-6-0-coming-soon/)

> that the underscored version of each main verb (filter_(), select_()
>   etc). is no longer needed, and so these functions have been deprecated
>   (but remain around for backward compatibility).

Comment: Yes, the new "tidy eval" approach is the way to go, I would say.

Comment: Don't know why but when executing the function returns error "invalid argument type"...

Comment: @ddl What's `packageVersion("dplyr")`?

Comment: it's ?.5.0? on my computer, I installed rlang to use quos, otherwise it says can't find the function quos, but then it goes "invalid..." am I missing other packages?

Comment: @ddl What's _?.5.0?_? 0.5.0.9004? If it's below that, try the latest development version: `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")`